# Discrepancy when calculating hosts

Tags: networking, subnet, hosts

## Background

I'm studying subnetting and find my answer to a question does not match that of the instructor.

NOTE: This is something I have chosen to learn about myself.  Not a course I am required to take.

What I've tried: searching online, contacting the site the course I'm taking is hosted on, searching for similar questions on Super User and other stack exchange sites.

## Question

Given the IP address 172.20.0.0. /16 calculate a subnet mask that will accommodate 100 hosts while maximizing the number of available subnets.

#### My answer

Using the formula 2^n -2 and starting with a class B subnet mask of 255.255.0.0 I calculated that I need to borrow 7 bits.

Initial subnet mask: 1111 1111.1111 1111.0000 0000.0000 0000

My answer: 1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1110.0000 0000 (255.255.254.0)

#### Instructor's answer

Instructor's answer: 1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1000 0000 (255.255.255.128)

I'd appreciate it if you could explain if/where I went wrong.

Comment: well, if you borrowed 8 bits, you would have 128 nets with 510 hosts each. in your teachers answer, they borrowed 9 bits, so they will have 512 nets with 126 hosts each. so you optimized for hosts per sub by taking only 7 bits, and the teacher optimized for subnets by reducing the size of each net to the smallest value > 100 that they could. that your answer is not correct is evident because there are 255 hosts in a /24 network, and because 7 bits can express 128 values and 6 bits can express 64 (too small), you need at least more than 24 bits and /25 is the smallest value that isnt too small

Comment: perhaps the confusion is that you got the 7bits correct, but you borrowed them instead of borrowing all the bits except them (16-7 = 9). since you want 126 hosts (128-2) those are the bits you leave, not the bits you borrow.

Comment: Correction: first comment should start "if you borrowed **7** bits"

Comment: There's an excellent [Q&A on Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) on that topic.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  I selected an answer but other answers and comments also  helped me figure it out.

Comment: @Zac67,Thanks I saw that.  But it didn't really jive with me.  I found [Calculate Hosts in a Subnet, networks in a subnet, & range of IPs](https://www.certificationkits.com/cisco-certification/ccna-articles/cisco-ccna-network-layer-conceptslayer-3/calculate-hosts-in-a-subnet-networks-in-a-subnet-a-range-of-ips/) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about 2^7 being the lowest power of 2 that is at least 100.
You're also right about the need to use up 7 bits for the IP netmask.

The 16-bit mask in this exercise is the upper-limit, which is actually
no limit, as it leaves 16 usable lower bits, while you only need 7 bits.

Since you are using 7 bits out of 32 bits, this leaves 25 bits that you
don't need. The netmask is then 25 bits, which does give
1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1000 0000 (255.255.255.128).

This netmask is used for the subnets that you will be creating.
As you have left 16-7=9 bits, you can create 2^9=512 different subnets,
where each has the above netmask (presumably to be allocated
internally to the fictional organization that was allocated the initial
16-bit netmask).

You have in your answer taken 7 bits out of the initial netmask of 16.
However, this part wasn't yours to take, as you were allocated by
whatever central authority/ISP only the lower 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

When a question specifies a number of Hosts, without specifying the number of networks, you want to count bits from the Right to the Left (the 25-32nd bits). The goal is to establish how many bits you need for hosts, and all the remaining bits will be for networks.

If the question specifies a number of subnets without specifying anything about the number of Hosts, you count bits from the Left to the Right (the 17-24th bits).

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile stepping back and focussing first on the outcome that is needed, then looking to the math.

Another way of asking the question would be "What is the smallest subnet - or smallest power of 2 - that can accommodate 100 hosts/IP's" - which is a subnet of 128 IP's, ie 0-127 which is represented in 7 bits.

Thus to work out the netmask you "0" the last 7 bits, and convert back, which means

11111111.11111111.11111111.1000000 = 255.255.255.128

I suspect that the stumbling block is this "Using the formula 2^n -2" - I'm not sure where this comes in or what it relates to, but that formula is not applicable here.